# Creating a widget with form that allows a POST request

Tags: php, post, yii, widget

On a few pages I need to include one box and a submit button. The view file uses the DatePicker to allow the user to fill in the input box. Upon hitting the "Go" (submit) button I would change the content below, based on the date.

I'm currently trying to use a widget as this code will be used on multiple pages. My problem now is I am wondering how I can take the POST request from the form and use it. Do I need a model with it? I will attach my current code below, but right now I am getting an error that $date is undefined. I knew it would give an error, but I am a little confused at what exactly I need to do for this.

Current code for widget:

> /protected/views/dateWidget.php

```
<div class="form">

    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'date-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
            'enableClientValidation' => true,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">
        Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.
    </p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($date); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($date,'date'); ?>
        <?php
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                'model' => $model,
                'attribute' => 'date',
                'language' => 'ja',
                'i18nScriptFile' => 'jquery.ui.datepicker-ja.js',
                'options' => array(
                    'showOn' => 'both',             // also opens with a button
                    'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',     // format of "2012-12-25"
            ),
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'size' => '10',         // textField size
                'maxlength' => '10',    // textField maxlength
            ),
        ));
        ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($date,'date'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Add'); ?>
    </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>
<!-- form -->
```

> /protected/components/DateWidget.php

```
<?php 
class DateWidget extends CWidget
{
    /**
     * @var CFormModel
     */
    public $form;

    public function run()
    {
//      if (! $this->form instanceof CFormModel) {
//          throw new RuntimeException('No valid form available.');
//      }
        $this->render('application.views.dateWidget', array('form'=>$this->form));
    }
}
?>
```

Question is then: How do I use use the $_POST from DateForm to effect other views/models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so clear what data exactly you want to alter basing on selected date because `$form` variable is ambiguous in your `dateWidget.php` view. Starting date's form widget like `$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(...))` you replace `CFormModel` instance passed from `DateWidget` by `CActiveForm` instance. That's what confusing...do you want to use your date field of `DateWidget` as part of some another form or as a separate nested form?

Anyway, to alter any data just before form submission one can attach `onSubmit` handler to that form:

```
jQuery('#date-form').submit(function(event) {
    // Any actions before submission
}
```

Considering a more general case with nested form and supposing that `$form` is `CActiveForm` instance in your view we can register the following script at the end of the view script (or in a separate JS file of your `DateWidget` - in any way you like) as shown below.

Please note that you have to write your own JavaScript functions `collectFormData` (that will gather main form's fields' values and place them in resulting plain JavaScript object) and `populateFormData` (that will set new values of the fields). That's because some fields of `CActiveForm` are custom and consist of more than a single input element (such as checkbox or radio buttons list). You can place these functions in a separate JS file of your widget.

Also to make `DateWidget` suitable for any form with any data we restrict it with code snippets which alter form's data moving these snippets to a separate PHP scripts that can be referred by `$url` property of `DateWidget`.

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript("alterPost", "
    jQuery('#" . $form->id . "').submit(function(event, submit) {

        // Checking whether form's submission has been requested
        if (submit) {

            // Allowing form submission
            return;
        }

        // Preventing form submission
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        // Getting selected date
        var dateString = jQuery(this).find('input[name$=\"[date]\"]').val();

        // Collecting data of main form...
        var jqMainForm = jQuery(this).parents('form');
        var mainFormData = collectFormData(jqMainForm.attr('id'));

        var self = jQuery(this);
        jQuery.ajax('" . $this->url . "', {
            'type': 'POST',
            'data': jQuery.extend({'dateString': dateString}, mainFormData),
            'dataType': 'json',
            'success': function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                // Populating main form by new values
                if (data['result'] === true)
                    populateFormData(jqMainForm.attr('id'), data['alteredFormData']);
                self.trigger('submit', true);
            }
        });
    })
", CClientScript::POS_READY);
```

A PHP script altering form data has to return the result as JSON:

```
<?php
$response = array(
    'result' => false
);
if (isset($_POST))
{
    // Analyzing dateString and form data, altering form data
    // $response['alteredFormData'] = ...;
    $response['result'] = true;
}
header("Content-Type: application/json");
print json_encode($response);
```